# $P(x>0|x+y>0)\;$ of two independently distributed Gaussian distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> I am given two independently distributed Gaussian distributions, $X$ and $Y$, with unknown means and variances. You randomly choose an $x$ and $y$ from these two distributions respectively. Given that $x+y>0$, what is the probability that $x>0$ in terms of the unknown parameters?

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$.

I know that $X+Y\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$. I considered using Bayes’ theorem.

$$P(x>0|x+y>0)=\frac{P(x>0)P(x+y>0|x>0)}{P(x+y>0)}.$$

Since I know the distributions of $X$ and $X+Y$, I know that the forms of $P(x>0)$ and $P(x+y>0)$ are that of integrating the Gaussian. However, I am unsure of the form of $P(x+y>0|x>0)$. I feel that this is much easier to calculate when observing the distribution of $X+Y$ on a 2D-plane, but I am not exactly sure how to write it in terms of the unknowns. Could someone please shed some insight on this? Thanks!

Edit: this was meant to be a conceptual question I believe, and should be left as a combination of integrals.

Comment: One insight is that if these are supposed to be i.i.d., you have four parameters where you should have only two, since $\mu_1=\mu_2$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$.

Comment: @CMonsour oh gosh sorry it should just be independently distributed, not i.i.d!

Comment: "I considered using Bayes’ theorem" This merely replaces the  computation of $P(x>0|x+y>0)$ by the computation of $P(x+y>0|x>0)$, for no obvious gain.

Comment: @Did I was thinking that if I plotted the PDF of X+Y I could make more progress constraining it to the x>0 plane instead, does that not work?

Comment: No. Sooner or later, you will have to use the joint PDF of $(X,X+Y)$. As long as you stay with marginals, for example the PDF of $X+Y$ alone, you cannot progress by even one iota.

Comment: @Did I see, what does the joint distribution look like mathematically? I’m not too familiar with non-independent distributions (from what I understand it’s about considering the covariance as well?)

Comment: Even covariances are not enough in general, you are rather after formulas similar to $$P(X+Y>0,X>0)=\int_0^\infty\int_{-x}^\infty f_Y(y)dyf_X(x)dx$$ But are you sure you need to solve the question **for any values** of the $\mu_i$s and $\sigma^2_i$s? 'Cause the answer shall be a nightmare to write down, even if rather simple conceptually.

Comment: @Did I think the answer was meant to be left as integrals. I feel like I still don’t have a proper grasp of what’s going on in that integral there, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Ah, then you already have $P(X+Y>0,X>0)$, and $$P(X>0)=\int_0^\infty f_X(x)dx$$ and since you know $f_X$ and $f_Y$, you are done.

Comment: @Did one last quick question, why is the limit of y from -x to inf?

Comment: Because $\{X+Y>0,X>0\}=\{X>0,Y>-X\}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you!